# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Development Server/Console Problems

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-console

Previewing a hybrid app in Worklight Console's MBS in Worklight v5.0.6 was a breeze as it worked right out the box.

Worklight 6.0 has proven to be a bit more tricky. Can someone point me in the right direction to getting my Worklight Console up and running?

Here is my Eclipse **console log**:

```
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0029E: An instance of server worklight is already running.
```

I have not altered any port information.
[image]

**Eclipse.ini:**

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

[image]

**Update:**
Completed the steps in Idan's response; the result in the Worklight Development Server console view in Eclipse:

> [err] 28  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1]
>   openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a
>   ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root
>   URL
>   [file:/Users/mwoods/Desktop/TestWorkspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar].
>   The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log
>   level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
>   [err] 460  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1]
>   openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
>       [err] 524  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class
>   "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
>       [err] 1  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a
>   ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU',
>   root URL
>   [file:/Users/mwoods/Desktop/TestWorkspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar].
>   The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log
>   level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

And:

> Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server
>   8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406 (en_US) [AUDIT ] CWWKE0001I: The
>   server worklight has been launched. [ERROR ] CWWKO0221E: TCP Channel
>   defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed. The socket bind
>   did not succeed for host * and port 10080. The port might already be
>   in use.

**SOLUTION:**
Changed port number and restarted my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be more interested in a step-by-step of what you've done. Please edit your question with the steps.

**Lets also try this very basic scenario:**

1. Have a brand new [Eclipse Jave EE **4.2.2** ("Juno" **SR2**)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2), new workspace, with Worklight Studio 6.0 installed
2. Go to the Servers view, start the Worklight Development Server
3. Create a new Worklight project
4. Right-click the project, choose `Open Worklight Console`

Does the above work?

---

**Based on the update to the question:**
The three errors regarding `WorklightPU` will always be displayed and are not related to your problem; we will try to remove these permanently in the future.

As for your problem: [find out which process occupies port 10080](http://databasically.com/2011/06/02/mac-os-x-find-the-program-running-on-a-port/), re-start Eclipse and  start the Worklight Development Server again.

Alternatively, you can change the new default port number:

1. Navigate to the Severs view
2. Expend the `Worklight Development Server` entry
3. Double-click on `Server Configuration`
4. Choose `HTTP Endpoint`
5. On the right side of the window, change the `port` value
6. Restart the server

Alternatively #2, restart the machine? :)

Comment: Completed steps 1-3 console: Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[ERROR   ] CWWKO0221E: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed.  The socket bind did not succeed for host * and port 10080.  The port might already be in use.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.

Comment: Do you have another Eclipse running? Is port 10080 taken...?

Comment: The three errors you've mentioned in the question are not relevant; they will always be displayed.

Comment: Check which program uses the 10080 port in OS X: http://databasically.com/2011/06/02/mac-os-x-find-the-program-running-on-a-port/

Comment: Just one Eclipse running, but there does seem to be something on port 1080: ➜  ~  sudo lsof -i :10080
Password:
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    9857 mwoods   54u  IPv6 0x8d1f1d519f0e7eb      0t0  TCP *:amanda (LISTEN)
➜  ~

Comment: Well, I don't know what that is... try identifying the process and kill it using the Activity Monitor app.

Comment: Couldn't changing the port to 8080 like Worklight v5 be a workaround, or is port 10080 of some significance to Worklight?

Comment: Not sure if we should kill Amanda (The Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver) Backup
Software

Amanda is a backup system designed to backup and archive many
computers on a network to disk, tape changer/drive or cloud storage.

Comment: We don't want clashes with existing installations so there is a new port number. You can change the port number - see my updated answer.

Comment: I changed the port number to 8081 as you described above and it worked for our the isolated environment. Tried this in my original environment and got my original error again: CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0029E: An instance of server worklight is already running.

Comment: You'll have to figure out the difference between yours and the isolated environment... You have something running already. Try killing the Java process and/or logging out and back in from your user or restart the machine. Maybe something is stuck.

Comment: Restarted my machine, didn't change anything and it just worked. You get the answer for all of you effort toward this question.